# Clear textfield in a form after submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form onsubmit="chat.sendMsg(); return false;">
    <label for="msg" style="float:left">Message:</label>
    <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" autofocus="true" placeholder="Type Your Meassage Here" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and the JavaScript that goes with it:

```
//For sending message
this.sendMsg=function(){ 
    msg=document.getElementById("msg").value;
    chatZone.innerHTML+='<div class="chatmsg"><b>'+name+'</b>: '+msg+'<br/></div>';
    oldata='<div class="chatmsg"><b>'+name+'</b>: '+msg+'<br/></div>';           
    this.ajaxSent();  
    return false;
};
```

All works, but when I submit the form, the text stays in the form. How to clear this textfield after I hit enter/click submit?

ps I dont use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `document.getElementById("msg").value = '';`

```
this.sendMsg=function(){ 
      msg=document.getElementById("msg").value;
      chatZone.innerHTML+='<div class="chatmsg"><b>'+name+'</b>: '+msg+'<br/></div>';
      oldata='<div class="chatmsg"><b>'+name+'</b>: '+msg+'<br/></div>';           
      this.ajaxSent();  
      document.getElementById("msg").value = '';//here
      return false;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add this

```
document.getElementById("msg").value='';
```

before the following statement:

```
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you both answered at the same time, so I coin flipped who got the Accpted answer, you lost :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Maurice not a problem dude. I am glad that I helped.